# A device that can see through hollow wood panel to find a hole in plaster covered wall?

Tags: hardware

**The Question**
Looking for a device that can see through a 'hollow wood panel section', to find a hole drilled in the plaster covered wall behind the 'hollow wood panel section' ?

Behind the plaster the wall is probably brick.

As written on the drawing below, there is a gap of probably under 8-mm between the 'hollow wood panel section' and the floor, and probably a gap of about 1-mm around the rest of the wood panel.
The 'hollow wood panel section' is approximately 1-meter high, 3-meters long, and 7-cm deep.
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Tut this is not a woodworking question so I've voted to close. The DIY stack is possibly a better fit on paper, but I don't know what type of technology you were hoping to find but there's no 'X-ray' vision equipment that will work through something of this thickness. There are inspection cameras/borescopes, but not sure if they can make the first 90° turn necessary, and if you want suggestions on that front you'll need to specify the rest of the dimensions (cable length can be limited), your budget and possibly your location too as some won't be available globally.

Comment: You'll have to move the "hollow wood panel section" and peek behind it.

Comment: @gnicko, I think it's safe to presume that's what they're trying to avoid doing LOL

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: About the only thing I can think is those heat lost finders for homes.  The hole might show up as a slight difference in temperature, but I would not bet on it.

Comment: Some stud finders might be able to do this.

Comment: Would be nice to explain why you want to find the hole.  to fix it, you will need to remove the panel anyway.  If wanting to make a hole in the wood panel, the plaster won't mind if you miss the hole.

Comment: I took an confused. Why can't you make a new hole? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant 8mm and not .8mm as shown in the diagram, perhaps a cheap endoscope. There are many on the "big river" shopping site costing well under USD50, and some claim to have heads as small as 5.5mm in diameter.

Example only:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, even though I found this device called 'Walabot DIY', which can see through drywall , and have posted it as an answer

Comment: Yes, 8-mm is what I meant, and I fixed that on the diagram –

Comment: If I put one of those endoscopes under the panel, and if the hole happens to be 50-cm up, then how would the endoscope reach up to find that, since it would only fall over

Comment: @whtdvce The endoscope is flexible but stiff; the one in the example I gave is 5 meters long. It will certainly be able to stand up more than a meter at least.